# How do I determine if my hardware can run Ubuntu?

Tags: server, 20.04, cd, cd-drive, lg

Is it possible to tell compatibility of ubuntu server with the help of motherboard model names?

I have an Old PC which don't support USB Bootable drives and am skeptical version 20.04 might not work on it. It has 2 gigabyte of ram and CPU is Core 2 Duo(Its an LG machine).

Comment: I have an old core 2 duo computer for testing purposes, and it works with current versions of Ubuntu. I hav tested it  both with Ubuntu Server and Lubuntu (version 22.04 LTS). So I think it should work for you too. There might be limitations due to the motherboard, but when the CPU has 64-bit architecture, the motherboard is usually matching it. Anyway, it is easy to try. Good luck :-)

Comment: the motherboard is gigabyte fsb 1066 can it work in it?

Comment: Understandable stuff. thanks for that!!

Comment: I'm replying here using a 2009 dell optiplex (c2q), is that considered old?   I used devices as old as from 2003 in QA_testing (*Quality Assurance testing*) releases up to 19.04 (2019-April release) and I'm talking there about pentium 4, M, D.. and before c2d era.  I use devices as old as from 2005 for current releases (with 2GB ram though usually more), but how you use the machine, what you'll do with it really determines requirements, OS being only one part of it. I still use boxes with 1GB & pentium M but how I use those machines differs to what I can do on this box.

Comment: Running an old Thinkpad R61 on Linux (it is not the age but the brand/hardware) you might check [these pages](https://ubuntu.com/certified). Thinkpads never failed  me on Linux in the last 20 years btw...

Comment: I don't know the details of you gigabyte fsb 1066 motherboard, but I *think* it will work with Ubuntu Server because it is made to work with c2d processors which should imply 64-bit architecture. Anyway, it is easy to try. You will notice if it works.

Comment: Well sure gotta Burn a cd and i think it's good to go!